# SQL - How to sum duplicate count result

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I have some problem about my query.

I want to categorize employee location and count it base on region, here my query:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN location = 'India' THEN 'Asia' 
        WHEN location  = 'Italy' THEN 'Europe' 
        WHEN location  = 'Singapore' THEN 'Asia' 
        WHEN location  = 'Australia' THEN 'Australia' 
        ELSE NULL 
     END) AS Region,  
    COUNT(location) AS Total_person 
FROM
    Location_tbl 
GROUP BY
    location
```

the result come like this :

1. Asia   = 1
2. Europe = 1
3. Asia   = 1
4. Australia = 1

The result I want is like this :

1. Asia = 2
2. Europe = 1
3. Australia = 1

Can you guys help me how to fix my query so I can get the result I want.

Comment: You should really have a  `Continent` column in your `Location_tb3` table .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the custom group in the `group by` -

```
select 
CASE WHEN location in( 'India','Singapore') THEN 'Asia' WHEN location  = 'Italy' THEN 'Europe' WHEN location  = 'Australia' THEN 'Australia' END as Region, 
count(location) as Total_person from Location_tbl 
group by CASE WHEN location in( 'India','Singapore') THEN 'Asia' WHEN location  = 'Italy' THEN 'Europe' WHEN location  = 'Australia' THEN 'Australia' END
```

Comment: @Jojo, glad that it helped you, please mark it as an accepted answer as it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Region, 
    count(Region) 
from 
    (select (CASE WHEN location = 'India' THEN 'Asia' WHEN location  = 'Italy' THEN 'Europe' WHEN location  = 'Singapore' THEN 'Asia' WHEN location  = 'Australia' THEN 'Australia' ELSE null END) as Region 
     from Location_tbl) tab 
group by 
    tab.Region
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    location,
    CASE
        WHEN location = 'India' or 'Singapore' THEN 'Asia' 
        WHEN location = 'Italy' THEN 'Europe'
        WHEN location = 'Australia' THEN 'Australia'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Region
FROM 
    Location_tbl
GROUP BY 
    location
ORDER BY 
    SUM(location);
```